# Best 10 of 12 in SQL

Tags: sql

Scoring for a running race series. They get points at each monthly race based on their finish. Their total score is their best 10 of 12 monthly races. How do I get that for each member?

tblRacePoints
memnum - Membership number
RaceNo - YYYYMM, e.g., 201910
Points

I want for each their total score of all races, total score of their best 10 of 12, and each of their lowest two scores for the year. Not everyone has done all the races so they may not have 12 entries for the year.

How do I write a query to do this, and then to rank them by their best 10/12 points?

Comment: You need to provide more info on your schema (table structure), some sample data, and also the required result.

Comment: Which Database you are using?

Comment: Assuming you are using a modern database, its probably going to be using row_number() or rank().

Comment: I gave the table structure in the original post:
tblRacePoints. fields:
memnum
RaceNo
Points

Currently in Access but could be any SQL based system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL database, you can use ROW_NUMBER as below to achieve your required output. Same logic can be used for some other databases too.

Note: Table structure is just an assumption.

```
WITH your_table(player_id,dt,points)
AS
(
    SELECT 1,'20190101', 100 UNION ALL  SELECT 1,'20190201', 200 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'20190301', 300 UNION ALL  SELECT 1,'20190401', 400 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'20190501', 500 UNION ALL  SELECT 1,'20190601', 600 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'20190701', 700 UNION ALL  SELECT 1,'20190801', 800 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'20190901', 900 UNION ALL  SELECT 1,'20191001', 1000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'20191101', 1100 UNION ALL SELECT 1,'20191201', 1200 UNION ALL

    SELECT 2,'20190101', 400 UNION ALL  SELECT 2,'20190201', 200 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'20190301', 300 UNION ALL  SELECT 2,'20190401', 400 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'20190501', 500 UNION ALL  SELECT 2,'20190601', 600 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'20190701', 700 UNION ALL  SELECT 2,'20190801', 800 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'20190901', 900 UNION ALL  SELECT 2,'20191001', 1000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'20191101', 1100 UNION ALL SELECT 2,'20191201', 1200
)
SELECT 
    player_id,
    YEAR(dt) Year, 
    SUM(Points) total_point
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id, YEAR(dt) ORDER BY Points DESC) RN
    FROM your_table

)A
WHERE RN <= 10
GROUP BY player_id, YEAR(dt)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of "100", "200", etc.? Why "01" after YYYYMM? Is there a way to dynamically select each month for the current year so that it's repeatable in future years? How do I find the lowest two for each memnum?

Comment: 100, 200...  Is just sample points. You can add some sample data from your table with your expected output. That will help.